# Fill List<int> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, random

In python you can do something like this:

```
arr = list(set(randint(-50, 50) for _ in range(10)))
```

I do know how to program a extension method that fills a array, list or whatever you need with random values.
I find this cumbersome though, and I really admire how you can do it in python.
Although, I only know of `Enumerable.Range,` which only can be used for generating fixed sequences, to my knowledge.

Is it possible in C# as well?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
List<int> = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(n => rnd.Next(-50, 51)).ToList();
```

Comment: Ah, I simply could not figure out how to invoke select together with Enumerable.Range. Thanks!

Comment: +1 That's the solution I just put together as well, but you beat me to it.

Comment: Wouldn't this possibly return duplicate numbers into the list?

Comment: That is not a problem Tim. That is how it is with random :) I don't mind it - If I wanted to avoid dublicates: I would not a normal range call and then just shuffle it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

```
var r = new Random();

var l = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => r.Next(100) - 50).ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. `Enumerable.Range` takes two arguments - start and count. You need to pass a 0 as the first argument.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, Something like...

```
Random r = new Random();
var ints = Enumerable.Range(0, 50).OrderBy(i => r.Next());
```

Comment: Note, this one is more like a shuffle (if thats what you are after) other wise the select is the better answer.

Comment: Note that there is a slight skew with that method when you get duplicate random numbers. The best shuffle method is a classic by Knuth, described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262480/how-to-shuffle-a-listt/1262521

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a variation, you could create a very simple static method like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<int> RandomSequence(int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        while (true)
            yield return r.Next(minValue, maxValue);
    }
```

And then use it like this:

```
    var numbers = RandomSequence(-50, 50).Take(10));

    foreach(var number in numbers)
        Console.WriteLine(number);
```

I love `yield return`... hehe c",)